# tornado can upgrade only to websocket error

Tags: django, websocket, tornado

I am using tornado for realtime application. I am using redis for this.
When I access the url `127.0.0.1:8888/2/` where 2 is my user id I get error saying `can "Upgrade" only to websocket`.

I dont know why I am getting this error. This error came because of my code or some issue with websocket ?

On my javascript i am doing `ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8888/" + user_id + "/");`

when i do `127.0.0.1:8888` it prints what i am printing in get() function in RequestHandler

Need advice

Comment: Does your handler class extend `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` class?

Comment: yes it does extends..

Comment: And does your route in description have trailing slash `/`? For me it looks like the route doesn't match. You can post your Python code in the question as well.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Can you print the value of `self.request.headers.get("Upgrade")` in `get()` or `prepare()`?

Answer (score 5):

This is the beginning of Tornado's GET method to handle WebSockets:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.open_args = args 
    self.open_kwargs = kwargs

    # Upgrade header should be present and should be equal to WebSocket
    if self.request.headers.get("Upgrade", "").lower() != 'websocket':
        self.set_status(400)
        self.finish("Can \"Upgrade\" only to \"WebSocket\".")                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        return
```

The error message you're getting is therefore caused by the absence of the "Upgrade" header missing in your request and it's not an error when you see this message when you simply GET the URL in your browser. However, if you use the JS code you provided and then you run `ws.send("message")` for example, you should be able to catch and handle this message in your Tornado WebSocketHandler:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    print(message)  # print the message to a standard output
    self.write_message(message)  # throw it back to client
```

Comment: How do I change/tap/modify/overload this @tornado.web.asynchronous function?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error message when trying to create a WebSocket in Tornado. All of the answers I found online, including here, were accurate but didn't solve the problem I was having.

I finally realized that since I was running my Tornado server behind nginx, this had nothing to do with my Python or JavaScript programs. Instead, this was a server configuration problem.

I found my solution by properly configuring my nginx server [using information from their site](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/).

If anyone is having the same problem, I wanted to suggest to also check for any applicable misconfigured server or load balancer settings.