# Why websocket with aiohttp server doesn't work

Tags: python, websocket, aiohttp

I was trying to understand how websocket  with aiohttp works, so I run this code  from docunentation https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#websockets :

```
async def websocket_handler(request):

    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request)

    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            if msg.data == 'close':
                await ws.close()
            else:
                await ws.send_str(msg.data + '/answer')
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
            print('ws connection closed with exception %s' %
                  ws.exception())

    print('websocket connection closed')

    return ws

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/ws', websocket_handler)])


asyncio.run(web.run_app(app))
```

The result I examined with curl:

```
curl  http://0.0.0.0:8080/ws
```

The message that I saw was:

```
No WebSocket UPGRADE hdr: None
 Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket"
```

Firefox shows the same message.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe someone knows what is the problem?

Comment: 1. Where does Firefox show the same message? I assume you needed some additional code to initiate a WS connection from Firefox -- if so, could you please add it to the question as well?

Comment: 2. What happens if you use some other WS server that's known to work, and test it with curl? Or use some other client to test? (e.g. https://github.com/vi/websocat)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34925832 and now after reading it, I think maybe the problem is that in both cases, the client doesn't tell the server that it expects to upgrade to WebSocket, but it's required

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried github.com/vi/websocat client and with it everything works. So the problem is how I tried to connect to WS server, not in aiohttp example.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still confused why they can't test the aiohttp websocket example given above with `websocat`, it's worth noting that there is an issue with the current version (`v1.11.0`)  via

```
brew install websocat
```

that means that `localhost` is not resolved properly.

It works fine if you substitute in `127.0.0.1` instead. For e.g:

```
websocat ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws
```